# Sending vCard to a Whatsapp user throught the WhatsAPI

Tags: vcf-vcard, whatsapp

I am trying to send a vCard using the WhatsAPI, here's my code:

```
    include "/var/www/whatsapp/whatsapi/whatsprot.class.php";
require "/var/www/whatsapp/whatsapi/vCard.php";
$w = new WhatsProt($sender, null, $nickname, false);
$w->Connect($proxy,$proxy_port);
$w->LoginWithPassword($sender_pass);
if($w->loginStatus == "connected")
{
    $data = array(
        'first_name' => 'John',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
        "display_name" => "John Doe",
        "work_city" => "New York",
        "cell_tel" => "972528452611"
    );

    $vcard = new vCard();
    $vcard->set("data", $data);
    $vcard->build();
    $w->sendVcard($number, "Test", $vcard->show());  
}
```

When trying to execute the php script I don't get anything on my whatsapp..

I have seen the following issue:

https://github.com/venomous0x/WhatsAPI/issues/708

https://github.com/venomous0x/WhatsAPI/issues/326

and none seem to help..

What is the problem?

Thanks in advanced,
Din.